# Regular expression to remove line breaks excluding lines with specific words

Tags: regex

I need to clean a sample test which looks like this:

```
a, b, c, d, e
line1a, "line1b", 


--,"


line1d",


li
ne
1
eXX

lin
e2a

",

,

310,

-
-

, line2eXX

"line3a",

220,


--


line3d,

"line3eXX"
```

The above sample needs to be like this:

```
a, b, c, d, e
"line1a","line1b","--","line1d","line1eXX"
"line2a","",310,"--","line2eXX"
"line3a",220,"--","line3d","line3eXX"
```

I am using a text editor (i.e., notepad++) to reformat the sample by regular expression.
This text file will be loaded in another program, i.e., MS Excel, R or python for further manipulation.

Structure and issues of the sample text are:

- It contains 5 columns (a to e) and multiple rows (3 rows in this example)
- Each line ends up with specific charactor ('XX') in column e
- There are some empty cells or cells with `--` which should be kept as data
- There are some data which breaks the line in the middle of value (i.e., line1eXX, line2a)
- All text data should be surrounded by `"` (numeric data should not be surrounded by `"`)

The goals are:

- Removing all line breaks excluding the last column (line1-3XX) to load one line as a row
- Surrounding all string data (excluding numeric data) by `"`

The better process may be:

1. Removing all line breaks (excluding `XX\n`)
2. Padding (surrounding) all data by `"` excluding numeric values

I tried replacing all line breaks excluding the last value of each row by searching `(?!XX)(?=\n|\r)` which will be replaced by empty ``, but it searched `XX\n` as well. I tried several expressions but all did not work.

If I could remove all line breaks excluding `XX/n`, all string values may be searched by something like `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}` but it searched some values with string and numbers, not all.

Are there any suggestions to obtain the desired result?
The header is not necessarily be considered in the manipulation.

Comment: Apparently you need an algorithm to do what you want, not only one regex

Comment: You might need multiple steps to get the final output. Try this as the first step, and then you would have to do some more replacements for the empty strings and strings around non digits https://regex101.com/r/rYG888/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird
Thank you, it solved the most critical part. As user2226755 mentioned, I will solve the remaining issues step by step.